# Consul-template if else condition

Tags: if-statement, puppet, consul, consul-template

I have below consul-template.

```
{{ range service "mysql_slave.mysql" "any" }}
host_name                      {{.Node}}
command                        check_nrpe!check_procs_1
{{end}}
```

I want to add if my hostname match "database-1" then command "check_procs_1" and others command "check_procs_2"

output

```
host_name                      node_server
command                        check_nrpe!check_procs_2

host_name                      database-1
command                        check_nrpe!check_procs_1

host_name                      webserver
command                        check_nrpe!check_procs_2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this issue we can use below fix.

```
{{ range service "mysql_slave.mysql" "any" }}

  {{ if eq .Node "database-1" }}

  host_name                      {{.Node}}
  command                        check_nrpe!check_procs_1

  {{else}}

  host_name                      {{.Node}}
  command                        check_nrpe!check_procs_2

  {{end}}

{{end}}
```